# OpenGL per-mesh material (shader)

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, game-engine, fragment-shader

So, I'm working on a simple game-engine with C++ and OpenGL 4. Right now I'm struggling with rendering imported models.

I'm using the FBX sdk to import fbx models using a very naive approach: basically I visit each node of the fbx and append the mesh data to a single big structure that is later used for rendering. However I want to be able to specify a different fragment shader for each material used by the model (for example a different shader for a car rims and lights).

As a reference, UE4 has a material system that allows the user to define a simple shader using a blueprint-like editor.

I would like to apply a similar concept to my engine, allowing to create a material object that specifies a piece of fragment shader code and a set of textures to use.

The problems I'm facing are:

1. It is clear that I must separate the draw calls for each model part that uses a different material, since I cannot swap program in the middle of a draw call (can I?): at this point, is it better to have a separate vao/vbo/ebo for each part or a single one and keep track of where a part ends and the next one begins? (I guess this is the best option)
2. Is it a good practice to pre-compile just the shader fragment and attach it to the current program on the fly (i.e. glAttach + glLinkProgram + glUseProgram) or is it better to pre-link an entire program for each material, considering that the vertex shader is always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you cannot change the program in the middle of a draw call. There are different opinions and tests on how the GPU will perform based on the layout of your data. My experience is that, if you are not going to modify your meshes data after you upload them the first time, the most efficent way is to have a single VAO, with two VBO: one for indices and one for the rest of the data. When issuing draw calls, you offset the indexes buffer based on the mesh data (which you should keep track of), as well as offseting the configuration of the shader attributes. This approach allows for a more cache-friendly and efficent memory access, as the block of memory will be contigous. However, as I mentioned, there are cases where this wont be the most efficent approach (althought I believe it will be still efficent enough). It depends on your hardware and driver.
2. Precompile and link all your programs before launching the render loop. Its the most efficent approach

As an extra, I would recommend you to look into the UBER shaders technique. This methodology is based on creating a shader for different possible inputs, and create a set of `defines` or sub-routines architecture which allows you to compile different versions of the same shader (for instance, you might have a model with a normal texture and you will probably want to apply bump mapping, but other models might not have this texture, so executing the exact same shader will result in undefined behaviour or crash).

Comment: "*you offset the indexes buffer based on the mesh data *" and "*offseting the configuration of the shader attributes*" Why do that? Not having to do that is the whole point of `glDrawElementsBaseVertex` and its ilk.

Comment: @NicolBolas and thats what I was refering to. I didnt mean he should modify the indexes or the vertex position in the buffers, my bad if it was unclear for you